# Jquery Selecting Right After appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

There is a button in my page and after clicking on it, it append some element with class **.select2-selection__rendered**. So i want to get its text after appending and it don't appends when the page loads, it appends when i click on a button and after that i want to use it in AJAX call but when i was testing it by alerting it's text i got nothing, its blank! . There is not a problem with appending. It appends it's  ***span***
 element.
Here is my script of selecting it's text.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
          function () {
        var postTitle = $(".select2-selection__rendered").text(); //selecting text
        $("div#sdf").click(function(){ //this div is like a button
              alert("Title is: " + postTitle);
          });
      });
```

==============================NEW EDITED===========================

Hey guys, i don't want to append something, i want to select the text of element that is being appended by script and that script only run when i click myButtn(name as example). 
And that script is not written by me and it's too long, i downloaded it...wait let me show you an example

[image: See the Above image....Now see this below image]

See the Above image....Now see this below image

[image]

Now any suggestions or help....? :(

==============================EDITED=================================

Comment: Provided sample works! Provide a scenario where it fails ..

Comment: Where is `append` ing code?

Comment: extra `function () {` is just question typo, right?! And i guess you should set `var postTitle = $(".select2-selection__rendered").text();` inside click handler

Comment: provide ur html code... please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you mean something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("div#sdf").click(function(){
    var select2 = $(".select2-selection__rendered").appendTo('body'); // replace 'body' by the DOM element to append to
    var postTitle = select2.text();
    alert("Title is: " + postTitle);
  });
});
```

or even

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("div#sdf").click(function(){
    var postTitle = $(".select2-selection__rendered").appendTo('body').text(); // replace 'body' by the DOM element to append to
    alert("Title is: " + postTitle);
  });
});
```

based on edited comment I think this should work :

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("div#sdf").click(function(){
    var postTitle = $(".select2-selection__rendered").text();
    alert("Title is: " + postTitle);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what i want, can you check the Edited text? Hope you can help.

Comment: I made a change. The main thing that is wrong in your code I think is the position of the `$(".select2-selection__rendered").text()`. If you do it on page load, the element is not appended yet by the external script. Then if you do it on click instead (when the content is there) that should work. Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){  

            var postTitle = $(".select2-selection__rendered").text(); //selecting text
            $("div#sdf").click(function () { //this div is like a button
                $(".select2-selection__rendered").append("<span style='color:red;'>hello</span>")
            });
        });  
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="select2-selection__rendered" >
        sample Text
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="sdf">Click Me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what i want, can you check the Edited text? Hope you can help.